# Equation for a surface given N points in 3d space?

Tags: bezier-curve

In 2D it is fairly well established how to generate a smooth curve from arbitrary points à la Bézier curves. Is there an equivalent to this for a smooth surface with arbitrary 3d points?

Comment: Search the web for _two dimensional spline_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Bezier patches. See my code: https://github.com/sjhalayka/bezier_surface
[image]